# changing the headline

Tags: templates, cv

I have a small problem with changing the headline in the example CV taken from - https://github.com/spagnuolocarmine/TwentySecondsCurriculumVitae-LaTex
On the left instead of "Skill" I would like to have "Languages" however by just changing the name in .cls file (using Overleaf ofc) it does not work or maybe I do something wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Cheers!

Comment: If i rename `Skills` to `Wombat` , i definitely see Wombat in the output.

Comment: Aside from that, the template provides a fixed layout and structure. You will get into more trouble in the future to customise it.